# Prevent setTimeout function from running when page on load in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have a table for students (**students**) in my postgres database like this :

| id | first_name | last_name | time_remind |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pers1 | pers1_name | 2022-07-30 21:30 |
| 2 | pers2 | pers2_name | 2022-07-30 20:38 |

I'm working on laravel and I use my controller to fill html table below here is my html blade:

```
<table class="table" id="timeTable">
  <thead>
    <th>first name</th>
    <th>last name</th>
    <th>remind time</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach ($students as $student)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$student->first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$student->last_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$student->time_remind}}</td>
        <script>
            function test() {
               alert('its time');
            }
            setTimeout( test, new Date('{{ $student->time_remind}}') - new Date());
        </script>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem here is that when loading the page or refreshing the page, the script fires automatically, so how to prevent that? please any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer of @PunyFlash :

```
<script>
   function test() {
       alert('its time');
   }

   if (new Date('{{ $student->time_remind}}') - new Date()> 0) {
       setTimeout(test, new Date('{{ $student->time_remind}}') - new Date())
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Modify your script and check if your date difference is negative:

```html
<script>
    function test() {
        alert('its time');
    }

    const alertAfter = new Date('{{ $student->time_remind}}') - new Date();

    if (alertAfter > 0) {
        setTimeout(test, alertAfter)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: it's work only for the first row and when inspect with the console I found this error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'alertAfter' has already been declared (at....

Comment: I find it based on your suggestion just remove (const alertAfter) :                                                                 
<script>
    function test() {
        alert('its time');
    }
    if (new Date('{{ $student->time_remind}}') - new Date()> 0) {
        setTimeout(test, alertAfter)
    }
</script>

Comment: edit your suggestion to accept it

Comment: remove alertAfter in if(){} and replace it with : new Date('{{ $student->time_remind}}') - new Date();